# Implementing generics to a primitive stack

Tags: java, generics, stack, primitive

I'm clueless as to how to implement generics in java, so I was hoping I could get some help turning my primitive implementation of a stack (below) into a program that uses generics (assuming it's possible to just change a few things, and not how to write a completely different program).

Below is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class LinkedListStack {

    public static Stack<Integer> stk = new Stack<Integer>();
    public static int min, push, top;

    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        //initialize random integer generator
        Random rand = new Random();

        System.out.println("Stack empty --> top = null, min = null");
        stackPush(rand.nextInt(50));

        //first value in the stack is the minimum until a smaller integer is pushed
        min = stk.peek();

        stackPush(rand.nextInt(50));
        stackPush(rand.nextInt(50));
        stackPop();
        stackPush(rand.nextInt(50));
        stackPush(rand.nextInt(50));
        stackPush(rand.nextInt(50));
        stackPush(rand.nextInt(50));
        stackPop();
        stackPop();
        stackPop();
        stackPop();
        stackPop();
        stackPop();
        stackPop();

        if (!stk.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("\nFinal stack: ");
            for(int x : stk) {
                System.out.print(x + " ");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.print("\nStack is empty!");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int stackPush(int pushInt) {
        try {
            stk.push(pushInt);
            if (stk.peek() < min) {
                min = stk.peek();
            }
            top = stk.peek();
            System.out.println("Push " + pushInt + " --> top = " + top +  ", min = " + min);

        } catch (EmptyStackException e){
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }

        return pushInt;
    }

    public static void stackPop() {
        try {
            stk.pop();
            if (stk.peek() < min) {
                min = stk.peek();
            }
            top = stk.peek();
            System.out.println("Pop --> top = " + top +  ", min = " + min);

        } catch (EmptyStackException e) {
            System.out.println("Stack already empty!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the desired behavior?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... The program has no intrinsic purpose, other than pushing elements onto the stack, checking for the minimum value to be pushed onto the stack, the last value to be pushed onto the stack, and to pop elements off the stack.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I'm asking for help for converting the above code to use generics, instead of primitives. It's the first sentence in the OP.

Comment: It is already using generics. The primitive values like `50` are autoboxed an inserted into the generic `Stack<Integer>`. Also, in most languages, generics can be primitive, just not in Java. Or are you trying to create an implementation that works with any type?

Comment: I'm attempting to do the latter (i.e. to work with any type, like using <E> or <T>). Apologies for not clarifying further, but I guess that proves my point that I know very little about generic types...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your class should not be static to accomplish this. It should also not expose its underlying implementation via public fields or via naming such as `LinkListStack`

Instead, you may create a class such as

```
class MyStack<E> {    
    private final Stack<E> wrapped = new Stack<E>();

    public void push(E element) {
        wrapped.push(e);
    }

    public E pop() {
        return wrapped.pop();
    }
}


public class Program {

     public static void main(String[] args) {        

     System.out.println("Stack empty --> top = null, min = null");

     MyStack<String> stack = new MyStack<>();

     stack.push("hello");

     stack.push("world");
}
```

**Note**:
Java has a built-in stack and re-inventing the wheel is bad practice except when done purely for educative/exploratory programming. This built in Stack is actually used to provide the underlying *wrapped* value which forms the backbone of our implementation.

Comment: Doing homework to learn something is never pointless. When one does his homework himself that is ....

Comment: Nonetheless I have seen many worse questions, and your answer is covering all those details I would have mentioned myself. Have my vote for that.

Comment: Just for the record: it is mainly about wording. If you would have written "be aware that java has a built-in stack and re-inventing the wheel is bad practice unless for learning" I would not have made my sarcastic comment in the first place.

Comment: @GhostCat I agree with your point. However the way I learn the best is seeing examples of what I'm trying to learn, in that specific context. I have seen examples of generic class implementations, but without the primitive implementation adjacent to it. The way I learn, that doesn't help me. In this case, however, seeing as I have a primitive implementation of a stack, but no idea how to implement a generic type version, seeing how someone else has written a generic implementation allows me to see where/what the differences are, and helps me to apply that in future.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I thought the point of generics was to allow any type of data (int, string, double, etc) to be used. In `class Program` if I use `stack.push(10); stack.push("hello");`, the statement `stack.push(10);` throws an error... Am I misinterpreting the purpose of generics?

Comment: The point is that you create an instance of a generic type by specifying a type for it to use. You can create a `MyStack<Integer>` and a `MyStack<String>`, and a `MyStack<YouNameIt>` but once created, each instance is bound to use the specified type (between the `<>`). It does not make sense to add an integer to collection of strings. Technically, it is possible to build such a generic, by using wrappers and generic methods but for a collection it does not usually make much sense. There are exceptions

Comment: How is that different from the implementation using primitives (in that `MyStack` can't contain multiple data types)? I'm not understanding the purpose of using a generic implementation if multiple data types can't be entered in the same stack...

Comment: The purpose, in this case, is that we can create any kind of stack we require without implementing one for the specific type of value we are using. It actually has nothing to do with primitive values, rather it has to do with how specific vs how general we are allowed to be. It is good to be as general as possible and operations such as `Push` and `Pop` do not depend on what the generic type is so long as it is known. It is known when we specify it as in `MyStack<String> = new MyStack<>();`. In short, type safe code reuse.

Comment: That makes more sense now. I had to try to change my original implementation to use Strings to understand what you meant; with my implementation, I can't just change `MyStack<Integer> = new MyStack<>();` to `MyStack<String> = new MyStack<>();`, because the `stackPush` and `stackPop` methods are written so they can only take integers as input (as declared in the method names). But with the generic implementation, the `push` method pushes the `E` (generic) element `element` to the stack.

Comment: @RThomP exactly

Comment: @RThomP I just realized I had a typo. I left pop as a `static` method which makes no sense and was invalid. Take a look at the update.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your stack generic but you will have to decide how you want to implement the comparison functionality since you it looks like you are maintaining a reference to the minimum element in the stack at any given time.

If you make it generic you have to think about what the minimum element would be for any possible type. Right now you are using Integers and the comparison is easy since integers are by their nature comparable.

I would do something like the following:

```
public class LinkedListStack<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public static Stack<T> stk = new Stack<T>();
    public static T min, push, top;
```

This also means that your push/pop methods will have to use compareTo rather than a straight integer comparison e.g.

```
 if (stk.peek().compareTo(min) < 0) {
            min = stk.peek();
 }
```

Keep in mind that if you plan to use your own types in this stack you will have to make them Comparable and implement a compareTo method.